# The tag [aiofiles] is used wrong – but quite consistently so

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag [aiofiles]'s description says *„To be used with programming questions that deals with AIO (APL Input Output) Files.“*

But is seems to be used exclusively for questions involving the [aiofiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aiofiles) Python module which offers asynchronous file operations.

What should we do? Remove the tag from questions about asynchronous file operations in Python, or maybe changing the meaning of the tag?

Comment: Are there any correctly tagged questions?

Comment: No, all 8 questions that show up are about Python and asynchronous code.

Comment: Off-topic: Is that [last question mark an anomaly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoP6t.png) on my end or do you have two different question marks on your keyboard?

Comment: It's an „interrobang“ — an exclamation mark and a question mark combined into one character.

Comment: Okay, I'll bang it in my system to not be confused in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I guess rewriting the tag excerpt and wiki to capture what the tag is really used for seems the most logical way to go forward

Answer (score 1):

All the questions in the tag were related to the [python library "aiofiles"](https://pypi.org/project/aiofiles) and not to the APL I/O files. I rewrote the excerpt as:

> aiofiles is a python library that is used to handle the local disk files present in asyncio applications. Use this tag for questions related to the python library only. Do not use the tag for APL I/O files.

and renamed the tag to [python-aiofiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-aiofiles). This should solve the issues with the tag.